# Android webview reset Http connections programmatically

Tags: android, webview

i'm using Android webview. Is there a way to reset the webview http connections programmatically? Thank's

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to reloading `WebView`? Can you explain what problem you want to solve with this .

Comment: when the webview loses the connection and then finds it again there is a slowdown that I have come to hypothesize is due to some hanging connection. I tried to reload the webview but I haven't solved it.